# Why do I always get this error when using 'apt-get' commands?

Tags: apt, 14.04, updates

I am using Ubuntu 14.04(with Unity). Just today(as of the date of this post) I did a `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` and at the end of the 'Upgrade' process I got the following error :-

```
Setting up crossplatformui (1.0.38) ...
 * Stopping ACPI services...                                             [ OK ] 
 * Starting ACPI services...                                             [ OK ] 
package libqtgui4 exist
QT_VERSION = 4
make -C /lib/modules/3.13.0-27-generic/build M=/usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/zteusbserial/below2.6.27 modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-27-generic'
  CC [M]  /usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/zteusbserial/below2.6.27/usb-serial.o
/usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/zteusbserial/below2.6.27/usb-serial.c:34:28: fatal error: linux/smp_lock.h: No such file or directory
 #include <linux/smp_lock.h>
                            ^
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [/usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/zteusbserial/below2.6.27/usb-serial.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [_module_/usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/zteusbserial/below2.6.27] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-27-generic'
make: *** [modules] Error 2
dpkg: error processing package crossplatformui (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 crossplatformui
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

From then on whatever `apt-get` command I use(so far as I know, except `apt-get update`) I keep getting the above error at the end of the process. But whichever `apt-get` command I use does what it has to without fail.(For example I tried installing blender with `sudo apt-get install blender` and it installed fine though it showed the above error.) After this I even got a kernel update(from 3.13.0-27 to 3.13.0-29 via the Software Updater), but even now the issue persists. How do I solve this issue?

Answer (score 3):

As this [question/answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/46540/fatal-error-linux-smp-lock-h-no-such-file-or-directory) surmises, `linux/smp_lock.h` was a file used in old 2.6 kernels. It no longer exists in Ubuntu, nor should it.

Your system it trying to compile a driver for an ancient kernel version. Just *look* at the error output:

```
.../usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/zteusbserial/below2.6.27 modules
```

Dump `ztemtApp` (whatever that is) and either replace it with a version for a modern Kernel or just ignore it. It's not compiling so if you're not missing anything, I'd suggest you just remove it and leave it at that.

Comment: right. This makes my issue clearer: I had installed a package that was unsupported by my kernel. So removing it resolved my issue. (BTW sorry for not *looking* at the error! I am just a newbie!)

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the results from [this](https://www.google.se/?gfe_rd=cr&safe=off#q=zteusbserial&safe=off) Google search result, you might get an idea of the cause of the trouble.

I think this issue is due to some broken package and to clean out broken packages, I think these are available in the *Safe start boot menu*

- "enable network"
- "clean"
- "autoremove"

Maybe try them out in that or similar sequence.
(This is from my own memory so check what there actually is and use them in a sequence that feels suitable to you.)

Also if you type ONLY (followed by <kbd>ENTER</kbd>)

```
$ apt-get
```

at the prompt you will see short info about each option. These should be the same ones as in the boot menu.

```
$ info apt-get
```

will tell more.

"Use the force, Luke"  (read up on the options - use them in a sane manner!)

Comment: If you look  at the results from that google search you might get an idea of the cause of the trouble.<br> As I have no idea what functionality the troublesome package is meant to provide, you will have to judge that yourself: i.e. do you need it? I can only suggest you remove it as it apparently didn't install properly - which is what the above is aimed at.

Comment: ^- elaborated enbough? ;-)

Comment: ah! right! Now i will post my answer giving due credit for your help!BTW include that comment in your answer properly.(Use the edit button just below the answer for that.)

Comment: Now it makes sense! I have up voted it! BTW since I no longer needed that package I just deleted it! :-)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue with help from the link that Hannu provided(Okay, the first search result, which is, [this](http://techbrahmana.blogspot.in/2013_03_01_archive.html)). From that link I understood that deleting the package named `crossplatformui` that had got installed(without my knowledge) when a Reliance data card was used in my PC recently would solve the issue. I did it with `Synaptic package manager` as shown by the image below:

[image]

As it is evident from the image I searched for the package and selected it for complete removal. After that I clicked Apply and the package was removed. After this I tried using `apt-get` commands and the above error(in my question) did not appear.

**PS:-**

For those wondering about the actual issue here, Oli's answer here clearly explains it. Quoting his answer:

> ..."Your system is trying to compile a driver for an ancient kernel version"...

This line of the error(in my question above) tells it all! :-

`/usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/zteusbserial/**below2.6.27**/usb-serial.c:34:28: fatal error: linux/smp_lock.h: No such file or directory`

(*Look* at it saying **below2.6.27** which means `crossplatformui` is only supported below kernel version 2.6.27 while my present kernel is 3.13.0 and so it caused the error.)